# Fitnesse function with multiple parameters

Tags: ios, swift, fitnesse

I am trying to create acceptance test with function with multiple parameters but all the time when test is run, I receive 'not found in...' exception.
According to http://fitnesse.org/FitNesse.UserGuide.WritingAcceptanceTests.SliM.ScriptTable both function calls should works.

Fitnesse table:

```
!define TEST_SYSTEM {slim}
|Script: My Test                                |
|login with username | Bob | and password | zxc |
```

or

```
|login with username and password; | Bob | zxc |
```

Fixture:

```
@objc(MyTest)
class MyTest: NSObject {
    let userName = "Bob"
    let password = "zxc"

    @objc func loginWithUsernameAndPassword(_ userName: String, _ password: String) -> Bool {
        let result = self.userName ==  userName && self.password == password
        return result
    }
}
```

No matter if I use _ for parameter name or not. Functions with one parameter or variables works fine. Is this some internal error or configuration issue?

Comment: Shouldn't the second _ be removed, `loginWithUsernameAndPassword(_ userName: String, password: String)` ?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson Nothing change

Comment: Not sure that ";" should be there in one of your examples, but I doubt that is the issue since it isn't in your first attempt.  What slim implementation are you using?  This works with Java I know, but I haven't tried it with Swift / Objective C.